# "took up" vs "took"

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Are there any difference between this two sentences?

> Alice **took up** the fan and gloves, and, as the hall was very hot, she kept fanning herself all the time she went on talking: `Dear, dear! How queer everything is to-day!
>
> Alice **took** the fan and gloves, and, as the hall was very hot, she kept fanning herself all the time she went on talking: `Dear, dear! How queer everything is to-day!

Comment: The sentences are not grammatically correct to begin with so it's very hard to pick up the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very much difference.

"Take up" in this sense is rather old fashioned. A modern author would probably use "picked up" instead.

Either "take", "take up" or "pick up" could be used here with very little variation in meaning.

To take up (in this sense) you are taking the object from where it lies, on the ground or a table. On the other hand, I can take something from someone else's hand. If you have my fan, I can take it from you. But I can't "take up my fan from you".

In the context of *Alice's Adventures in Wonderland*, the rabbit has dropped his fan and gloves, and run away. Alice (who was giant at the time) "takes up" the fan off the ground, and by fanning herself becomes small again.

Comment: Not so fast!  There may be other better answers. It is best to wait before accepting an answer.